# Bind vertical scrolling in one element to horizontal scrolling in another and map the height of one to the width of the other

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have built a very simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/aq8ht4df/) which takes the vertical scrolling from one container, and uses it to scroll left and right in a second container.

Currently as the height of container A has no correlation to the width of container B, the scrolling will end sooner or later depending on heights, margins and so on if the elements inside each container.

I need some formula to make the scrolling relative between the two elements if this is possible.

JS:

```
const multiElementScroll = ( elem1, elem2 ) => {
  elem1.onscroll = function() {
    elem2.scrollLeft = this.scrollTop;
  };
}

multiElementScroll( div1, div2 );
```

Basic HTML:

```
<div class="scroll-box" id="div1"> 
    <h1>A</h1>
    <h2>B</h2>
    <h2>C</h2>
    <h2>D</h2>
    <h2>E</h2>
    <h2>F</h2>
    <h2>G</h2>
    <h2>H</h2>
</div>

<div class="scroll-box scroll-box-h" id="div2"> 
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
    <h2>4</h2>
    <h2>5</h2>
</div>
```

And SCSS:

```
.scroll-box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #d99;
    
    &-h {
        display: flex;
        height: 100px;
        width: 1000px;
        overflow-x: overlay;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        
        h1, h2 {
            display: inline;
            margin: 0 200px 0 0 !important;
        }
    }
}

.scroll-box h2 { margin-top: 50px; }
```

Probably makes more sense in the fiddle.

Is there some formula to pass in the height and width and calculate the scrollLeft px offset? Apologies if this is badly worded.

Comment: So you want to make synchronised scrolling with different length? Calculate percentage.

Comment: YES! If that is possible, which I assume it must be (I am hopeless at the mathematical stuff.

Comment: Hey @JanPfeifer do you think this is possible to mimic this behaviour using the body as the first element. I am trying to achieve this by adding some css properties to the body. The problem is that `const c = elem1.scrollTop / m;` returns NaN when the selector is the body. 

Here is the original jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/aq8ht4df/ which works thanks to your update.

Here is the new fiddle which I am trying to update to work with scroll on the body. http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/4b2e5cdj/

Alternatively I would be more than happy to update my question, or ask a new question.

Comment: Ah I think I have done it using `const c = window.scrollY / m;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to calculate and set relative scroll position:

```
const multiElementScroll = ( elem1, elem2 ) => {
    elem1.onscroll = function() {            
        const m = elem1.scrollHeight - elem1.offsetHeight;
        const c = elem1.scrollTop / m;

        const m2 = elem2.scrollWidth - elem2.offsetWidth;
        elem2.scrollLeft = m2 * c;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is calculate percentage of vertical scroll and use that percentage to calculate width scroll:

```js
const multiElementScroll = ( elem1, elem2 ) => {
  elem1.onscroll = function() {
    const scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
    const height = this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight;
    const width = elem2.scrollWidth - elem2.offsetWidth;
    elem2.scrollLeft = (scrollTop * 100 / height) * width / 100;
  };
}

multiElementScroll( div1, div2 );
```

```css
.scroll-box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  border:1px solid #d99
}
.scroll-box-h {
  display:flex;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:overlay;
  overflow-y:hidden
}
.scroll-box-h h1,
.scroll-box-h h2 {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 200px 0 0 !important
}
.scroll-box h2 {
  margin-top:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-box" id="div1"> 
    <h1>A</h1>
    <h2>B</h2>
    <h2>C</h2>
    <h2>D</h2>
    <h2>E</h2>
    <h2>F</h2>
    <h2>G</h2>
    <h2>H</h2>
</div>

<div class="scroll-box scroll-box-h" id="div2"> 
    <h1>1</h1>
    <h2>2</h2>
    <h2>3</h2>
    <h2>4</h2>
    <h2>5</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the heights and widths removing the full (scrollable) size from the visible one, as the value that you read or set is the lower one (top and left). Calculate the percentage and multiply the width:

```js
const multiElementScroll = ( elem1, elem2 ) => {
  elem1.onscroll = function() {
    var percent = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.clientHeight);
    elem2.scrollLeft = (elem2.scrollWidth - elem2.clientWidth) * percent;
  };
}

multiElementScroll( div1, div2 );
```

The intermediate variable `percent` is only added for readability, you can inline it if you prefer so. Use